# How to get QGIS project title with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I would like to get the project title with PyQGIS to use it as a parameter of a Python script.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the project title with

```
title = QgsProject.instance().title()
```

See the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Project/QgsProject.html?highlight=title#qgis.core.QgsProject.title)